# Is it possible to require an optional variable in a subclass?

Tags: swift

Let's say I have an class `Place`, looking like this:

```
class Place{
    let name:String
    let description:String
    let location:CLLocation?
}
```

The `location`-variable is optional.

Is it possible to create a subclass of this class where the `location`-variable is **required**?

This would be possible if I removed the location-variable from `Place`, and simply did this:

```
class LocatedPlace:Place{
    let location:CLLocation
}
```

But is there a way to have an optional variable in a class, and make that same variable required in a subclass?

I have tried `override let location:CLLocation`, but get the message:
`Cannot override with a stored property 'location'`

Comment: No, you would break polymorphism because you would not be able to assign nil.

Comment: @Sulthan But that's the point. If I instantiate an object of `Place`, I could assign nil. But I want a "kind" of this object where I know location is required.

Comment: @Sti That's not how polymorphic works. `let place: Place = LocatedPlate(); place.location = nil` ... now what happens?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: @Alexander I see the problem, but that would only be a problem if `location` was a `var`. Since it's a `let`, it is immutable either way, and could never happen. The only difference I would experience was that I would have to unwrap the value if I don't cast it as `LocatedPlace` first.

Comment: However, optional is not just a flag on a variable, it's a whole different type. It's the difference between `Optional<CLLocation>` and `CLLocation`. `CLLocation` is not a subtype of `Optional<CLLocation>` therefore this cannot work. The only thing you can do is to create a second non-optional variable. The contract would be probably better described using protocols anyway. Even if it's a constant it gets assigned anyway in `init`. A constant is not the same as a `var` with a getter.

Comment: You can't change the type of `location` for the reasons already given. You could override the  initialiser in you subclass and generate a runtime error if no location was provided, but the property would still be an optional and you would need to unwrap it when you referred to it.

Comment: @Sti that was just 1 example. I think you're thinking about it too narrowly. Try to break it, and see what you come up with. Here's an example: `func foo(place: Place) { let distanceToLocation = location.map { $0.distance(to: here) } ... }` The runtime is supposed to guess that you want an implicit wrapping of `LocatedPlace.location` into an optional, so that `map` can be called on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments on your question you can't make `location` non-optional in the subclass since that would violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

`CLLocation?` and `CLLocation` are different types, just as `String` and `CLLocation` are different types and you wouldn't expect to be able to make `location` a `String` in `LocatedPlace`.

What you can do is enforce your requirement through the object intialiser by making the `location` value mandatory and hiding the superclass initialiser:

```
class Place{
    let name:String
    let description:String
    let location:CLLocation?

    init(name: String, description: String, location: CLLocation? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.location = location
    }
}

class LocatedPlace: Place {

    private override init(name: String, description: String, location: CLLocation? = nil) {
        super.init(name: name, description: description, location: location)
    }

    init(name: String, description: String, location: CLLocation) {
        super.init(name: name, description: description, location: location)
    }
}
```

Note that the `location` property of `LocatedPlace` instance will still be an optional and you will need to unwrap it when you reference it.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you're actually trying to do, here it how I would model this:

```
import CoreLocation

protocol Place {
    var name: String { get }
    var description: String { get }
    var location: CLLocation? { get }
}

struct LocatedPlace: Place {
    let name: String
    let description: String
    var _location: CLLocation

    var location: CLLocation? { return _location }
}
```

Comment: This isn't quite right either. You need to name your protocol something else and both `Place` and `LocatedPlace` need to implement that protocol. The two structs then need different initialisers so that `LocatedPlace` enforces a non-optional `location`